# Where to find french dictionary for ispell?

Tags: emacs, dictionary, ispell

I am editing documents in French with Emacs, `ispell` comes will English dictionary by default. When I try `ispell-change-dictionary`, it proposes `francais-tex`, `francais7` and `francais` in the list. But after choosing anyone, and doing `ispell-word`, it tells me `Error: The file "/usr/lib/aspell/francais" can not be opened for reading`. Then I check the folder `/usr/lib/aspell`, indeed there is no "french" file in it.

So could anyone tell me where to find these french dictionaries and put them in the folder?

PS: I am using ubuntu...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to install package like `aspell-fr` or something like. issue command `apt-cache search aspell-` to get list of all available dictionaries, or use graphical tools to find dictionary...