# How to enable Norwegian spelling check in emacs?

Tags: emacs, aspell, ispell

I want to run ispell for Norwegian and possibly other languages in emacs (Ubuntu 14.04).

I've installed the aspell-no package, do a ispell-change-dictionary, set it to no, upon which it says "using norsk dictionary", then I run ispell. This leads to:

> Error: The file /usr/lib/aspell/norsk can not be opened for reading.

Rightly so, the file doesn't exist, but a bunch of others: no.dat, norwegian.alias, etc.

Am I missing something? This is a problem similar to 
[Where to find french dictionary for ispell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245658/where-to-find-french-dictionary-for-ispell),
but it seems to differ in that the answers mentioned there don't solve it.

Comment: Call `ispell-change-dictionary` and press tab. Is `no` listed in the completion window or `norsk` only?

Comment: On bash-command line type `aspell dump dicts`. What is listed there?

Comment: The `ispell-change-dictionary` listing includes `nb`, `nn`, `norsk`, and `norsk7-tex`, but no `no`. The `aspell dump dicts` listing includes `nb`, `nn`, and `no`.

Answer (score 2):

The commenters pointed me in the right direction. The answer is actually as simple as this: Call `ispell-change-dictionary` and set it to `nb`. Works as a charm.
The different values listed above are still confusing, though ..

Comment: If your language is not listed, you might have to install it first. On Linux, install the package `aspell-no` with your favorite package manager. Then reload emacs.